# How to reformat a text document from a point cloud?

Tags: python, blender, point-clouds

I'm trying to convert a list of points from my 3D scanner. The scanner outputs the points in the format of "X Y Z Intensity R G B"
Example:

```
-20.909 -7.091 -1.204 -1466 119 102 90
-20.910 -7.088 -1.203 -1306 121 103 80
-20.910 -7.090 -1.204 -1456 123 102 89
```

I would like to convert it to this (just dropping the intensity and color data while adding commas and parentheses)

desired output:

```
(-20.909, -7.091, -1.204),
(-20.910, -7.088, -1.203),
(-20.910, -7.090, -1.204),
(-20.910, -7.088, -1.204),
(-20.909, -7.088, -1.204),
(-20.910, -7.088, -1.203),
(-20.909, -7.090, -1.202),
(-20.905, -7.091, -1.204),
(-20.907, -7.090, -1.204),
(-20.907, -7.090, -1.204)
```

I'm trying to do this so I can import the point cloud data into a script inside of Blender3D. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: typos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def convert_line(line):
    parts = line.split(maxsplit=3)
    return f'({parts[0]}, {parts[1]}, {parts[2]})'

with open('data.txt') as in_:
    lines = in_.readlines()

converted = [convert_line(x) for x in lines]

with open('output.txt', 'w') as out_:
    out_.write(',\n'.join(converted))
```

This is a very basic script but it should do just what you need, assuming no data is corrupt. Change `data.txt` and `output.txt` with appropriate file names (paths).

Comment: I'm sorry for being so ne new to this, but how would I run this script?

Comment: @TripwireEOD Save it as a file, for example `script.py`. In command line (e.g. CMD), while positioned in the directory where the script and data are, write `python script.py`. It will create the output file in the same directory. You might need to use `python3 script.py` if the other fails.
If you do not have python in PATH, something like this might also work: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe script.py`
Please accept the answer if it worked :)

Comment: thanks for the reply ! I tried it as you said, but no luck. this is what I did, maybe you can point out my mistake. I opened a new .txt file and copied in you code and changed the Data.txt and output.txt to CBN_Test.txt and CBN_Test_output.txt. then I saved the text document as ```Converter.py``` with UTF-8 format. The CBN_Test.txt, CBN_Test_output.txt and Converter.py are all in a folder called ```Converter``` on my desktop. In the CMD I navigated to D:\users\ME\Desktop\converter>. then I typed ```python converter.py```, pressed ENTER and nothing happened. ideas?

Comment: Everything you explained seems perfectly correct. In CMD (in any directory) run `python --version` - if it prints something like `Python 3.8.3` let me know, it that case something else is the problem. I would assume you do not have standalone Python installed. Do you have Python in `C:\Program Files` or `C:\Program Files (x86)`? If not, download the latest version from python.org and then try to run the script. It might be the case that you have Python bundled with Visual Studio for example, but it won't behave the same as when installed separately.

Comment: I Downloaded python 3.8.3. it located at C:\Users\ME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.8. when I type "python" it bring me to the MS store python page. should i re-dowload it from there?

Comment: That is only a shortcut. Rightclick on it and then choose `Open file location`. See where it takes you, and use the absolute path of that `.exe` to run the script like this: `"path_to_exe" converter.py`
I think you do not have python in your PATH environment variable. Using the absolute path should work regardless.

Comment: To simplify things if you plan on using python in the future, I would suggest to add it to PATH: https://geek-university.com/python/add-python-to-the-windows-path/

Comment: im sorry this is taking up so much of your time. The ```.exe``` is located at C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32. when I nav to that DIR in CMD and type ```python converter.py``` It comes back with "python: can't open file 'converter.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory". I have moved the input and output files and converter.py into the python38-32 folder so thats in the same dir.

Comment: To simplify everything, just move the input file and the script back to desktop and navigate to that folder in CMD, like you did in your original explanation. Then run this (including quotation marks): `"C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe" converter.py`

Comment: Sorry, I'm still getting an error "C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe: can't open file 'converter.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory". could the error be to the python.exe and the converter.py files being on diffrent disks? (C: and D:) Also I noticed the Converter.py is still showing as a text document.

Comment: I solved the problem. After I nav'ed to D:\Users\ME\Desktop\Converter Directory, I typed in ```python converter.py.txt``` and it worked! Previously I was just typing ```Python converter.py``` which gave me the errors. Thank you so much for the help. I really appreciate it!

Comment: I did not foresee that one hahah. I would suggest you go in any File Explorer window, click on `View` on top and select `File name extensions` on the right side so that things like this don't confuse you again. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def convert(line):
    x, y, z, intensity, r, g, b = line.split()
    return f'({x}, {y}, {z})'

with open('input.txt') as f:
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as out:
        lines = f.readlines()
        out.write(',\n'.join(convert(line) for line in lines))
```

Comment: Please consider adding a few lines about how it works, etc.